# Failing with multiply instances

Tags: android

I`m trying to launch an Intent filter from one process to run an activity of another proccess.

This is pretty easy:

```
    protected void startIntent()
    {
       Intent i = new Intent(target);
       i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
       i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
       context.startActivity(i);
     }
```

Now as my topic says, I am willing to run the target activity as **multiply instances**.

Each instance of that activity is supposed to do some operation and then it has `finish();`

So now I call `startIntent();` 4 times in a row.

I want to have 4 instances parallel in the stack of the same target activity (each activity will finish after it does some operations. with finish(); ).

The problem is that it doesn't work properly. I tried some LoadTest, and when I call the method 3 (or below) times in a row it works fine, but when I call startIntent() 4+ times some instances of that activity never get launched(for example the second Intent in the order that has been called).

This is some warning I get:

> WARN/ActivityManager(966): Duplicate finish request for HistoryRecord{4367ed60     {com.test.targetActivity/com.idan.external.callingActivity}}

Btw: In the target activity I've setted in the manifest the flag:

```
android:launchMode="standard" (also tried without it, and it didnt work).
```

Any idea?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have an answer, but your problem does seem a little unusual. Can you tell us more about the purpose of your app? Launching 4 Activity instances simultaneously seems like a peculiar way to achieve a task, and there may well be a better solution.

Comment: I agree with Dave. What are you doing in each activity that requires its own activity? It could be that android forcing closed some of the activities or something weird due to threading.

Comment: Dave,Falmarri: the purpose of my target activity is to reciver a message from an outside server, and active another activity in it. so if i get 4 messages.. i need to run the target activity 4 times with diffrent message from the server for each instance.

Comment: Do they need to run simultaneously, or can each message be handled one by one?

Comment: when i use startActivity(..) it's a simultaneously command, isnt it?

Comment: Did you try sending different extras for each intent to try and "force" the OS to allocate a new Activity?
Also, I'm not sure it is correct to use FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP. As it clear previous intents and put the new one on top...